# OS 標準ではなく、IJCADのカラーダイアログを表示するには？

Tags: ijcad, vb.net

カラーダイアログの参照を行うのに `Dim cd As New ColorDialog` を定義するとWindowsのカラーダイアログが表示されます。これではなくIJCADのカラーダイアログを表示したいのですが定義の仕方を教えて戴きたい。

Answer (score 0):

参照設定でIJCADのAPIを参照し、ColorDialogの型を定義する際に
GrxCAD.Windows.ColorDialog
にしてみたらいかがでしょうか。

具体的には下記のコードで実現可能と思います。

```
<CommandMethod("TestCDialog")>
Public Sub TestCDialog()
    Dim cd As New GrxCAD.Windows.ColorDialog
    cd.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

上記はインスタンス作成時に型を定義していますが、
Importsステートメントで定義してもよいかと思います。

Comment: 参照設定でGCAD2023 ObjectLibraryを参照していますが Dim cd as New GrxCAD.Windows.ColorDialog でエラー「型'GrxCAD.Windows.ColorDialog'は定義されていません」が出ます。Imports GrxCAD.ApplicationServicesを入れてみましたが「インポート'GrxCAD.ApplicationServices'で指定された名前空間または型が、パブリックメンバーを含んでいないか、あるいは見つかりません・・・」のメッセージが出ます。参照設定ー追加ー参照には何も表示されません。何か定義が間違っているのでしょうか？ご教授お願い致します

Comment: Program Files-ITJP-IJCAD 2023 PROの中にgmap.dllとgmdb.dllを見つけたのでこれを「参照」に追加してみたところ実行時に次のエラーが出ました。

Comment: ファイルまたはアセンブリ 'gmap, Version=1.0.8458.28417, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'、またはその依存関係の 1 つが読み込めませんでした。間違ったフォーマットのプログラムを読み込もうとしました。